# Is there a proper way to create functions that accept dynamic tuples?

Tags: typescript

Is there anyway to do this in a more concise way?

```
interface html {
  <A>(array: TemplateStringsArray, propA: A): (props: [A]) => Node;
  <A, B>(array: TemplateStringsArray, propA: A, propB: B): (props: [A, B]) => Node;
  <A, B, C>(array: TemplateStringsArray, propA: A, propB: B, propC: C): (props: [A, B, C]) => Node;
  <A, B, C, D>(array: TemplateStringsArray, propA: A, propB: B, propC: C, propD: D): (props: [A, B, C, D]) => Node;
  <A, B, C, D, E>(array: TemplateStringsArray, propA: A, propB: B, propC: C, propD: D, propE: E): (props: [A, B, C, D, E]) => Node;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can post an answer, but afaik, until we get [variadic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) I think this is the best you can do. You'll see this pattern even in the official typings for variadic functions (see the types for `Object.assign`), so it's probably the only way for now.